# Awk if condition is not working if use ||

Tags: awk

I'm searching writing a script to grep a word and compare the timings of the error. If the time is not equal to 01 or 04 then it should print the error time

```sh
grep -e "Socket disconnected" -e "App Server collections connection state[False]" log-2019-10* |
awk '{if ((substr($2,1,2) != "04")) print (substr($2,1,8));}'
```

```
15:00:03
19:02:44
19:02:44
21:27:48
21:27:48
20:20:13
01:49:25
01:49:54
```

But when I use

```sh
grep -e "Socket disconnected" -e "App Server collections connection state[False]" log-2019-10* |
awk '{if ((substr($2,1,2) != "01") || (substr($2,1,2) != "04")) print (substr($2,1,8))}'
```

it is printing all the timings

```
04:56:55
04:56:55
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:56:26
04:55:27
04:55:28
04:55:24
04:55:24
15:00:03
19:02:44
19:02:44
21:27:48
21:27:48
04:55:22
04:55:22
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:28
04:55:28
04:55:24
04:55:24
20:20:13
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:26
04:55:26
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:25
04:55:23
04:55:23
04:55:23
04:55:23
01:49:25
01:49:54
04:55:23
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:26
04:55:26
04:55:23
04:55:23
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:24
04:55:25
04:55:25
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

When you use `if ((substr($2,1,2) != "01") || (substr($2,1,2) != "04"))`, the condition is true when either the time is not “01”, or the time is not “04”; this is always true, including for “01” (which is not “04”) and “04” (which is not “01”).

You should use `&&` instead:

```sh
grep -e "Socket disconnected" -e "App Server collections connection state[False]" log-2019-10* |
awk '{if ((substr($2,1,2) != "01") && (substr($2,1,2) != "04")) print (substr($2,1,8))}'
```

which produces

```
15:00:03
19:02:44
19:02:44
21:27:48
21:27:48
20:20:13
```

This is an instance of [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): you want to check that the time is not either “01” or “04”, *i.e.* `!("01" || "04")`, which is equivalent to `!"01" && !"04"`.

Incidentally, you can combine perform the `grep` filtering in AWK:

```sh
awk '(/Socket disconnected/ || /App Server collections connection state\[False]/) && substr($2,1,2) != "01" && substr($2,1,2) != "04" { print substr($2,1,8) }' log-2019-10*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen . This is working . Is there a way where i can add a sequence of number
like i want to ignore 00 to 05 from the output. Can i do that

Comment: That’s a rather different question! You can use comparisons on numbers: `if (0 + substr($2,1,2) > 5) print substr($2,1,8)`.

Comment: The second one is working well 
 grep -e "Socket disconnected" -e "App Server collections connection state[False]" log-2019-10* | awk '{if (0 + substr($2,1,2) > 5) print substr($2,1,8)}'
15:00:03
19:02:44
19:02:44
21:27:48
21:27:48
20:20:13